# Yii CJuiTabs options - how do they work?

Tags: jquery, yii

*[jQuery UI Tabs - Content via Ajax](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ajax.html)* shows what the Ajax tabs should look like:

```
<li><a href="ajax/content1.html">Tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href="ajax/content2.html">Tab 2</a></li>
```

But this [Yii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yii) example code is for one Ajax and one static tab:

```
class ROrganizationTabs extends CJuiTabs {
    public $tabs = array(
        'Statistics'=>'content',
        'Main Data' => 
        array('ajax'=>array('user/dashboard.loadone','id'=>1)),
    );
}
```

Which gives me HTML code like this:

```
<li class=""><a href="#yw12_tab_0" title="#yw12_tab_0">Statistics</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="#yw12_tab_1" title="#yw12_tab_1">Main Data</a></li>
```

Both are static, not Ajax.

And I can't find in the page code (HTML, and JavaScript) where Yii placed the Ajax URL for Ajax tab. Where is it?

Comment: i need to update an url, regardless my another page element events and reload a content of Tab

Comment: does it work when you don't extend it?

Comment: Yeah, this is kind of confusing. That `ROrganizationTabs` code makes it look like you are doing something to the default functionality of CJuiTabs, so that could be breaking something but it's impossible to tell. Can you get the default CJuiTabs to work, as described here? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiTabs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell I would say the jQuery plugin does the Ajax and URL handling. Without a detailed look at the JavaScript code there, the man page of the plugin states:

> Tabs supports loading tab content via
>   Ajax in an unobtrusive manner.
>
> The HTML you need is slightly
>   different from the one that is used
>   for static tabs: A list of links
>   pointing to existing resources (from
>   where the content gets loaded) and no
>   additional containers at all
>   (unobtrusive!). The containers' markup
>   is going to be created on the fly: [...]

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#Ajax_mode

The complete  tabs behaviour is just wrapped in this line

```
jQuery('#yw0').tabs({'collapsible':true});
```

Take a look at the Yii playground example: http://www.yiiplayground.cubedwater.com/index.php?r=UiModule/jui/ziiTab